# Pandas how to get this?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python3 pandas to read a CSV file which contains 4 columns, named `{a,b,c,d}`.

Now I want to add a new column `e` where the data is given by `(d-last.d)/last.d`.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you think the below answer worked for you, then please do not forget to select it as the right one by clicking on the 'tick' button.

Comment: system tip me "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes" when i click this button,I don't know why

Comment: Thats because of the timer. Come back anytime and select it the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and for select last value [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'b':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'c':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'd':[5,3,6,9,2,10],
})

df['e'] = df['d'].sub(df['d'].iat[-1]).div(df['d'].iat[-1])
print (df)
   a  b  c   d    e
0  4  7  1   5 -0.5
1  5  8  3   3 -0.7
2  4  9  5   6 -0.4
3  5  4  7   9 -0.1
4  5  2  1   2 -0.8
5  4  3  0  10  0.0
```